# Context of using declaration and ambiguous declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

There is a quote from the sec. 3.4.3.2/3:

> Given X::m (where X is a user-declared namespace), or given ::m (where
>   X is the global namespace), if S(X, m) is the empty set, the program
>   is ill-formed. **Otherwise, if S(X, m) has exactly one member, or if
>   the context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X, m)
>   is the required set of declarations of m.**

Definition of S(X,m) is the following sec. 3.4.3.2/2:

> For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,
>   m) is defined as follows: Let S (X, m) be the set of all declarations
>   of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S (X, m) is
>   not empty, S(X, m) is S (X, m); otherwise, S(X, m) is the union of
>   S(Ni , m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and
>   its inline namespace set.

Now consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace N
{
    int cout = 6;
}
using namespace N;

int main() {
    using ::cout;//error: reference to ‘cout’ is ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand thar error. The code above does not contradict to the rule:

> if S(X, m) has exactly one member, or if the context of the reference
>   is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X, m) is the required set of
>   declarations of m.

Can you explain the sense of that rule?

Comment: You forgot to mention which `cout` you *expected* to that `using` clause to identify.

Comment: For functions, a set of all declarations with multiple values (may) have no conflict and ambiguity, for classes and object instance it is ambiguous which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry, I suspect you are misinterpreting what "if the context of the reference is a *using-declaration*" means. "In the context of a *using-declaration*" does not mean "when used in a *using-declaration*". It instead means "when the reference is the subject of a *using-declaration*". Suppose your code is changed as follows:

```
int main() {
    using N::cout;
    std::cout << "value=" << cout << '\n';
}
```

Note the use of the unqualified `cout` in `std::cout << "value=" << cout << '\n'`. The context of that unqualified reference is the *using-declaration* `using N::cout`.

Another way to look at what the standard means is that a *using-declaration* takes precedence over a *using-directive*.