# byte and ambiguous symbol due to using declarations?

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, c++17

We are a ***C++ library***. For years we had `typedef unsigned char byte;` in the global namespace. User programs and other libraries provided compatible definitions of `byte`, so there were no problems.

C++17 added `std::byte` and changed semantics of a byte. Now we need to be more hygienic by avoid global namespace pollution; and we need to insulate ourselves from `std::byte`. Our change is to move our `byte` into our namespace.

We are witnessing an unexpected failure as we test the impact of changes. The program below ***does not*** follow best practices (according to Herb Sutter at [Migrating to Namespaces](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/migrating-to-namespaces/184404271)), but we expect it to be a typical use case for ***user programs***.

```
$ cat test2.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

 // Testing this to select the right byte type
using byte = CryptoPP::byte;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  CryptoPP::byte block1[16];
  std::byte block2[16];
  byte block3[16];

  return 0;
}
```

The program above has competing definitions of `byte` due to `std::byte`, `CryptoPP::byte` and the `using namespace ...`. As I said, I know it leaves something to be desired.

Compiling the program results in (sans the unused warnings):

```
$ echo $CXXFLAGS
-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra

$ g++ $CXXFLAGS test2.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
test2.cxx: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test2.cxx:12:3: error: reference to ‘byte’ is ambiguous
   byte block3[16];
   ^~~~
test2.cxx:6:28: note: candidates are: using byte = CryptoPP::byte
 using byte = CryptoPP::byte;
                            ^
In file included from stdcpp.h:48:0,
                 from cryptlib.h:97,
                 from test2.cxx:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstddef:64:14: note:                 enum class std::byte
   enum class byte : unsigned char {};
              ^~~~
```

In the compile error, what is catching me by surprise is, we explicitly removed the ambiguity with `using byte = CryptoPP::byte;`.

We hoped to advise users who depend upon `byte` in the global namespace (and who use the `using namespace ....` declarations) to use `using byte = CryptoPP::byte;` until they had time to update their code.

My first question is, why is the compiler claiming `byte` is ambiguous after it was told the to use `CryptoPP::byte` via the `using` declaration? Or is this just plain wrong, and we are lucky we got that far along during the  compile?

A second related question is, is there any advice we can give to users so their existing code compiles as expected after we migrate `byte` into our namespace? Or is the only choice for users to fix their code?

I think this has something to do with the issue: [Context of using declaration and ambiguous declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24268165/608639). The `using byte = CryptoPP::byte;` is tripping me up since the ambiguity was removed.

---

Regarding comments below and *"I think there's a lesson to be learned from this about intelligent use of namespaces from the get-go"*, there's some  backstory. This is Wei Dai's [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/). It was written in the early 1990s, and used unscoped `byte` because C++ namespaces were not available. Namespaces appeared about 5 years later.

When namespaces were introduced, everything was moved into `CryptoPP` except `byte`. According to [source code comments](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L197), `byte` remained in global namespace due to *"ambiguity with other byte typedefs"*. Apparently, there was contention long before C++17. Early C++ compilers probably did not help the issue.

In hindsight, we should have planned for some version of C++ doing this (in addition to a bad `using namespace ...` interaction). We should have already moved to `CryptoPP::byte`, and *possibly* provided an unscoped `byte` for convenience to user programs with appropriate warnings.

Hindsight is always 20/20.

Comment: A better solution, IMO, would be to not have `using namespace std;` anywhere.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude - Yes, agreed. We took some blowback for suggesting similar. Some folks cautioned against it because it effectively means a library is setting policy for a program. I also feel that we should not be making policy decisions for others. Also see [PR 438, Use ::byte instead of byte](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/438#issuecomment-315553526).

Comment: _we explicitly removed the ambiguity with using byte = CryptoPP::byte;_ ... No. `using` declarations can be used to create aliases. Their purpose isn't to _remove ambiguity_.

Comment: `using byte = CryptoPP::byte;` is just a declaration. It declares an alias for  `CryptoPP::byte` in global namespace, but it does not in any way "elevate" this version of `byte` over any other version present in global namespace.

Comment: @AnT - The whole "keyword" phrasing of [[dcl.typedef/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.typedef-1)] is highly confusing then.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Good point. I wonder what is the intended purpose of that "keyword" phrasing.

Comment: @AnT - Nothing more concrete in the standard that I could find. But in function scope, the alias does seem special. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dc4fd61100b5177

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *using-directive* in the global namespace [causes unqualified name lookup to consider all declarations in the nominated namespace as members of the global  namespace](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup.unqual#2). They stand on equal footing with other members of the global namespace, and so adding additional declarations to the global namespace will not resolve an existing ambiguity in unqualified lookup.

Such declarations *can* resolve qualified name lookup ambiguities (e.g., the lookup of `byte` in `::byte`), because [that lookup only examines namespaces nominated by *using-directive*s if a declaration is not found](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup#namespace.qual-2). That might be where you got the idea.

Comment: I don't see the OP convincing clients to fixup their code and use `::byte` instead of `byte` however. No more than they coerce clients to use `CryptoPP::byte`. I think there's a lesson to be learned from this about intelligent use of namesapces from the get-go.

Comment: @StoryTeller Right, if their client can use `::byte` they could just use the correctly qualified version. I just included it to address the likely source of OP's misconception.

Comment: @T.C. and StroyTeller - Thank you very much. Sorry about making you guys play language lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be strongly inclined to demand that people explicitly name the namespace of your library. C++ is about knowing types, not guessing them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

/* simulate CrypoPP for the MVCE */

namespace CryptoPP {
    using byte = unsigned char;
}

/* never, ever, ever. People who do this invite their own destruction.
using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;
using byte = CryptoPP::byte;
*/

namespace OurFunkyLibrary
{
    using byte = std::byte; // or CryptoPP::byte, as you wish
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // explicit
    CryptoPP::byte block1[16];

    // explicit
    std::byte block2[16];

    /* if your users really can't stand knowing which type they are using... */
    using namespace OurFunkyLibrary;
    byte block3[16];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"never, ever, ever do this"* - Lol... That's precisely the case we are trying to engineer around. I'm beginning to think there is no solution to the problem because of the ambiguity from using two different namespaces with the same symbol but different semantics. Those who want to do it are going to have to suck it up and fix their code since c++ does not appear to allow us to select either `std::byte` or `CryptoPP::byte`.

Comment: @jww if your users are inviting their own destruction, it's not for you to stand in their way.